# bazel py_proto_library is not defined

Tags: python, bazel

**BUILD:**

```
cc_proto_library(
    name = "yd_fieldoptions_cc",
    deps = [":yd_fieldoptions"],
)

py_proto_library(
    name = "yd_fieldoptions_py",
    deps = [":yd_fieldoptions"],
)

proto_library(
    name = "yd_fieldoptions",
    srcs = ["yd_fieldoptions.proto"],
    deps = [
        "@com_google_protobuf//:descriptor_proto",
    ],
)
```

**Error**

> bazel build -s //field_options:yd_fieldoptions_py
>   BUILD:11:1: name 'py_proto_library' is not defined (did you mean 'cc_proto_library'?)

**version:**

Build label: 0.14.0- (@non-git)

protobuf verson: 3.5.0

Comment: Not sure I understand what exactly the question is, but unless you have a custom rule `py_proto_library`, I'd side with bazel. At least its [documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/python.html) does not suggest one would be there from the get go.

Comment: sorry! I want generated yd_fieldoptions_pb2.py by yd_fieldoptions.proto. so i found protobuf.bzl have py_proto_library rule.I want to use this rule.

Comment: But then you have to [load](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/functions.html#load) it, before you can refer to it.

Comment: If you try [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=py_proto_library) around here for `py_proto_library`, you'll get good number of hits including suggestions of different protobuf external dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You might be thinking of this rule: https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/protobuf.bzl

In order to use it you have to `load` the bzl file in the BUILD file: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/concepts.html#loading-an-extension

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of `py_proto_library` has some hacks related to it.
Some of the toolchain/library references are only valid inside the Protobuf repository. In order to use the rule `py_proto_library`, you have to manually bind those references in your own repository.

I have a very rough example that demonstrates how to bind some (but definitely not all) of those references in order to make `py_proto_library` work in your repository.

You can checkout the example [here](https://gist.github.com/izzyleung/2fe240e470ad5f7c270b29fcb972c6ca).

This is a **very rough** implementation, though it works, I don't have any idea whether this will work with a more complex scenario.
You have been warned.

---

However, if you really really want to make things work.
You can invoke the  Protobuf compiler directly, then export the generate Python file to a `py_library`.

This is guaranteed to work, though this requires more code.

```
# This generates the Protobuf Python code using the protoc compiler
genrule(
    name = "yd_fieldoptions_compiled_python",
    srcs = ["yd_fieldoptions.proto"],
    outs = ["yd_fieldoptions_pb2.py"],
    cmd = "$(location @com_google_protobuf//:protoc) -I=proto --python_out=$(@D) $<",
    tools = ["@com_google_protobuf//:protoc"],
)

# Setup a py_library target to be used by your code.
py_library(
    name = "yd_fieldoptions_py",
    srcs = [":yd_fieldoptions_compiled_python"],
    deps = [
        "@protobuf_python",
        "@pypi_six//:six",
    ],
)
```

Also, you have to include the following info in your `WORKSPACE` file.
Those are used to download the necessary dependencies, you might have to change those URL as well as versions for Protobuf-Python according to your need.

```
new_http_archive(
    name = "pypi_six",
    url = "https://pypi.python.org/packages/16/d8/bc6316cf98419719bd59c91742194c111b6f2e85abac88e496adefaf7afe/six-1.11.0.tar.gz",
    build_file_content = """
py_library(
    name = "six",
    srcs = ["six.py"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
    """,
    strip_prefix = "six-1.11.0",
)

new_http_archive(
    name = "protobuf_python",
    url = "https://pypi.python.org/packages/14/03/ff5279abda7b46e9538bfb1411d42831b7e65c460d73831ed2445649bc02/protobuf-3.5.1.tar.gz",
    build_file_content = """
py_library(
    name = "protobuf_python",
    srcs = glob(["google/protobuf/**/*.py"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    imports = [
        "@pypi_six//:six",
    ],
)
    """,
    strip_prefix = "protobuf-3.5.1",
)
```

BTW, the code included above does not have gRPC plugin included.
If you are looking for a gRPC enabled Protobuf library, you have to include the gRPC repo, then include necessary the plugin in the corresponding rule.